# How do I make sure a 1-D array is valid using a while statement?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, while-loop

I am trying to check that each integer (Array) is valid (Between 0 and 30). A problem occurs as the line telling the user the score is invalid runs but the variable doesn't seem to be False, and I don't know why, can anyone fix this?

Here is the code in question:

```
while valid_score == True and program_running == True:
      for counter in range(0,6):
            print("How mant points did player", counter + 1 ,"earn?") 
            score_earned[counter] = int(input())

            if score_earned[counter] < 0 or score_earned[counter] > 30: 
                  print("That value was invalid as it was lower than 0 or `above 30!")`
                  valid_score = False

            else:
                  valid_score = True


            total_score = score_earned[counter] + total_score

      valid_score = False
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the traceback?

Comment: Unrelated, but first argument of `range(0, 6)` is unnecessary.

Comment: The reason the while loop doesn't exit when it finds an invalid score is because your for loop is still going to run to completion from 0 to 6 before the while loop checks if it is valid. You probably want to break out of the for loop when you find an invalid score. I also do not see the point of the while loop as you set valid_score to False at the end always so the while loop only ever runs once.

Comment: At least from what you've shown, you aren't creating an array/list prior to iterating. Set score_earned = [0 for x in range(6)] prior to while loop. Still have a problem? Edit - as other people are mentioning, the for range(0, 6) pretty much negates the usefulness of the while loop. Start a count before the while loop, that will take the place of counter variable.

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. "the variable doesn't seem to be False" Does "the variable" here refer to `valid_score`? You set that to false at the end of the while loop. So do you mean that it's not `False` right after the for-loop? Why do you have a while loop with a condition that `valid_score` be `True` when you set it to `False` at the end of the loop, guaranteeing it to exit after the first iteration?

Answer (score 1):

You could just prevent any `points` attempted to be entered that are not in the range you desire, before passing those values to your dictionary.
You could do this with a `while` loop that will only accept that range of `points`

```
score_earned = {}  
players = 5

for i in range(1, players +1):
    points = -1
    while points < 0 or points > 30:
        try:
            points = int(input('Enter points for player {} between 0 and 30: '.format(i)))
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter points between 0 and 30')
    score_earned[i] = points

total_score = sum(score_earned.values())
print('The total score is: {}'.format(total_score))
```

Comment: @G_M Op was casting `int` to the input without accounting for `non-int`s being entered, so I didn't want to add another element that they were either not concerned about or not up to speed with

Comment: It seems like all the other answers don't account for that possibility now either, maybe adding it could make your answer stand out as a better way overall?

Comment: @G_M ty appreciate input

Comment: @G_M haha for sure I'm a new Im barely through my second month of coding and I just play along with time complexities and hope I'm doing well ahha stealing your learning material btw :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you've misunderstood how the loops work

```
while valid_score == True and program_running == True: # <-- This will not break while running inner loop
      for counter in range(0,6): # <-- this loops independently
            ....
```

My suggestion is to adjust your code to look like this:

```
  for counter in range(0,6):
        print("How mant points did player", counter + 1 ,"earn?") 
        score_earned[counter] = int(input())

        if score_earned[counter] < 0 or score_earned[counter] > 30: 
              print("That value was invalid as it was lower than 0 or `above 30!")`
              valid_score = False
              break # <-- this ends the loop early

        else:
              valid_score = True

        total_score = score_earned[counter] + total_score
        if not program_running == True:
              break
```

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and made a working version of your code. You seem to be making several mistakes. This should help clear up your misconceptions. Consider adding a type() check incase someone decides to enter a string.

```
score_earned = {} #python dictionary is an associative array
counter = 1
valid_score = True

while valid_score == True: #and program_running == True: #program_running variable is never assigned
    print("How mant points did player", counter, "earn?") 
    score_earned[counter] = int(input())

    if score_earned[counter] < 0 or score_earned[counter] > 30: 
        print("That value was invalid as it was lower than 0 or above 30!")
        valid_score = False

    total_score = score_earned[counter] + total_score #currently doing nothing with total_score
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the for loop is somewhat confusing since you are repeatedly looping between 0 and 6, when you probably are just wanting to use a while loop only and increment a counter value while it is less then 6.

I wrote up this example which converted what I could understand from the logic of your code to only one while statement:

```
counter = 0
valid_score = True
program_running = True

while valid_score and counter < 6 and program_running:
    print("How mant points did player", counter + 1 ,"earn?") 
    score_earned[counter] = int(input())

    if score_earned[counter] < 0 or score_earned[counter] > 30: 
        print("That value was invalid as it was lower than 0 or `above 30!")`
        valid_score = False

    total_score += score_earned[counter]  # Not sure you want to add to the total score when invalid
                                          # Probably better to add to total score in else statement
    counter += 1  # Increment counter variable keeping track of number of iterations
```

You proabably can modify this some to match your expected result, but this should help you understand how to use a while loop and counter better.